# Openshift: cannot clone repository

Tags: git, openshift

I've installed RUBY, git and rhc and followed the setup wizard. 
Then I try: `git clone http://{{myAppName}}.rhcloud.com testApp`
NOTE: {{myAppName}} I've replaced with my app's name. I actually took the URL from the web console, and this is the URL which I'm supposed to see my app in.

But I get this:
fatal: repository 'http://{{myAppName}}.rhcloud.com/' not found
remote: Cannot GET /info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

Any idea what's wrong with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

The URL `'http://{{myAppName}}.rhcloud.com/` is not a git repository; that is the address at which your application is available for use.

The git repository associated with your repository is available in the "source code" link in the upper right of the application administration page; it looks something like:

```
ssh://5526bf70fcf933ac4900002b@{{myAppName}}-{{myDomain}}.rhcloud.com/~/git/{{myAppName}}.git/
```

According to [the documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-fedora.html#_command_line_rhc), if you created your application using the `rhc` tool you should already have a local clone of the repository available.

Otherwise, you would run:

```
git clone ssh://5526bf70fcf933ac4900002b@{{myAppName}}-{{myDomain}}.rhcloud.com/~/git/{{myAppName}}.git/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after trying a lot I've finally found a way to get the git URL.
In command line I type:

```
rhc apps
```

This gives me the list of apps and their git URL and now it works.